# NEB calculations in VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, nudged-elastic-band

In NEB calculations, I am getting much higher energy values.

```
00    -395.94910849  = 0
01    37.30329488    = 37.30329488+395.94910849 = 433.25240337
02    1018.48104960  = 1018.48104960+395.94910849 = 1414.43015809
03   1001.09925193   = 1001.09925193+395.94910849 = 1397.04836042
04   37.79655317   = 37.79655317+395.94910849 = 433.74566166
05  -395.95035434 = -395.95035434+395.94910849 = -0.0012458499999752348
```

In literature, I have seen energy values in a few eV. I am not getting what could be the possible reason for getting such high energy values. What next I can do in this case. If anyone is familiar with this type of issue, please suggest.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?

Comment: @NikeDattani I stop these calcultions after getting unusal results. I don't need answer any more, change the idea of work in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Since the author of this question [no longer needs an answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/neb-calculations-in-vasp?noredirect=1#comment25139_10624), we are prioritizing more urgent questions in the unanswered queue, but if anyone want to answer this question, please ping me in a comment or click Flag and say so, and this Community Wiki answer will be deleted.